# High Disk IO with Network and CPU spikes

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have a Linode server that has been under load for a few hours. The configuration is 2 CPU Cores, 4GB memory, 80GB SSD storage mounted as 1 partition, 500MB swap. There's a second hard drive of 30GB which is also SSD. Software is Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.52, PHP-FPM (Most sites using 8.0, some on 7.2 and 8.1). I'm also using fail2ban and iptables for protection.

Here's the graph that Linode's dashboard shows me

[image: Linode Dashboard]

Earlier I was getting spikes in network which corresponded to spikes in CPU usage. It was enough to make the websites on the server not respond (500 error) during the spikes. Now, I have constantly higher than usual disk IO.

Linode has a built in DDoS protection and I asked them about it and they said it didn't trigger any actions from DDoS protection layer. Does this look like an attack?

I've tried several commands but none of them has given me any clues so far.

**iostat**

[image: iostat]

**iotop -a** :

[image: iotop]

**vmstat 1 10**

[image: vmstat]

**top** : Again there's no process constantly on the list

[image: top]

Comment: 150 `tps` on `sda` and 200 `IOPS` on the graph for >6 hours and no processes in `iotop`?

Comment: Not no process but processes come and go with only a few kb/s read and writes. Is it possible to get an average over time by each process?

Comment: you can run `iotop -a` to accumulate stats. Read `man iotop`.

Comment: The problem with that is when the process exits, its removed from the list. So not useful still

Comment: I don't know if there should be so many www-data processes. I've added the screenshot to the question

Comment: You can try an alternative `iotop` implementation, it remembers dead processes. https://github.com/Tomas-M/iotop